# Why would WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken return this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to implement a forgot password function into my asp.net mvc 3 application using C#  razor views.
The following error occurs when I submit the "forgot Password" form...

```
  To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

The following line seems to be the trigger...

```
   var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email);
```

I'm coming in on another developers code here so, I'm still working my way through all the code.

I've tried the other solutions to the above error found online but none seem to work.
I don't want to post up a load of code so is there steps I can take or a number of places I should be looking into in order to eliminate the possible reasons for this error.
Please note this is an asp.net mvc 3 app, using razor views, c# and build with visual studio 2010.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: in ASP.net, you can provide different implementations of MembershipProvider. For WebSecurity to work, the type of your  MembershipProvider must inherit from ExtendedMembershipProvider. The built-in type that inherits from ExtendedMembershipProvider is SimpleMembershipProvider

Comment: where can I check the MembershipProvider ? Web config has nothing.

Comment: Static property `System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider`

Comment: I'm assuming I should find it in "Add Reference" .NET window to be added as a using statement to the controller file in question....I not seeing it in the listing ?

Comment: The class is `Membership`. It's in the namespace `System.Web.Security`. Assembly is `System.Web.ApplicationServices`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, my controller has the using statements -  System.Web.Security; and  System.Web.ApplicationServices; do I need to manually create a Membership class aswell ? still returns the same error with these using statements included ?

Comment: Easiest way is to just debug your application then add ` System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider` to your watch. No need to modify your code.

Comment: how do I add to watch ?

Comment: For what it's worth when I drill into System.web.ApplicationServices - then System.web.security where I have a list of Membership classes. How do I add to the MembershipProvider class to allow for inheritance of ExtendMembershipProvider ?